# How can I add gradle support to an existing intellij project?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have an intellij project that has gradle files in it(build.gradle, settings.gradle, etc.) and I have the project working in intellij. The issue is that intellij can't find any 3rd party libraries so I need to link the gradle project to it. How can I do this to an existing intellij project or at least be able to resolve 3rd party libraries so that the classes don't show up as red in the editor?

I'm on version 2016.1.2 145.972

Comment: After discussing with a co-worker, this may be an issue with intellij 2016 versions. He had the same issue when he upgraded and had to downgrade to intellij 14. I'm going to submit a bug report to JetBrains.

Answer (score 1):

You can click on the "+" symbol on the Gradle tool window and *attach* the project. If you don't see the window, use View | Tool Windows | Gradle to bring it up. (Or use the square icon on bottom left). You may then have to click the refresh icon to bring in the dependancies (in case IntelliJ didn't do it).

Refer: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/working-with-gradle-projects.html

Alternately, you could just re-import the project freshly using gradle.
*Import Existing Project -> Import project from External model -> Gradle*

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, in the question I forgot to mention that when I go to view->tool windows I don't see the gradle option even though I have the gradle plugin enabled. Is there a way that I can get the gradle option back?

Comment: I followed the instructions from https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html#migrating_from_intellij (Migrate by creating a custom Gradle build file) and Gradle works fine.